# How can I make my document file path more dynamic?

Tags: asp.net, ms-word

C:\Users\513041\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication7\WebApplication7\Document.dotx

I think what I am looking for is something along the lines of:
~\Document.dotx

Where the computer simply looks for the document at the root directory of the location of my project.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `Server.MapPath`. That will give you the root location of your web application from your local filesystem's point of view.

So:

```
Server.MapPath("~/images/123.png")
```

translates at runtime into the string `c:\users\whatever\projects\mywebapp\images\123.png` or wherever your app lives.

If you're not in a page, control, controller, etc., then you can grab the server object with `HttpContext.Current`, so `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/whatever.doc")`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Server.MapPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

If C:\Users\513041\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication7\WebApplication7 is a root of your application then

```
string pathToFiles = Server.MapPath("~/Document.dotx");
```